# "Startup disk" in "About this Mac"

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive

I noticed that on when I go into "About this Mac" on my iMac I see a parameter named "Startup disk" while on my MacBook I do not... Is this because I have multiple disks in my iMac and only one in the MacBook?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's because the Mac sees multiple bootable disks.

Or multiple bootable volumes on the internal drive.